# Shortest code to load an excel sheet with header?

Tags: python, excel, file-read

I have an excel file, from which I want to load a specific sheet. Assuming I know its name, and that there is only one row of header, what is the shortest code capable of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pandas' [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) function you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(FILENAME)
```

Your document will load into the `df` dataframe.

There are additional options you can pass to `read_excel` if you need to skip rows, manipulate headers, parse dates, etc. too.

Comment: By default, row 1 is assumed to be the headers, and become the data frame column names

Answer (score 1):

If you have pandas, it's really easy:

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile('file_name.xlsx')
sht = xl.parse('Sheet1')
```

Comment: what happens to the headers?

Comment: The first row labels are automatically converted to the dataframe's column indexers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `xlrd` installed,

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

# Load file
filename = 'file.xls'
sheet = open_workbook(filename).sheet_by_name('Data')

# Read data
header = [sheet.row(0)[i].value for i in range(sheet.ncols)]
data = [[sheet.row(i)[j].value for j in range(sheet.ncols)] for i in range(1, sheet.nrows)]
```